# How to replace a text with hyperlink using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

I want to replace a word with hyperlink on every post. So i used this code.

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('Ronaldo', '<a href="www.ronaldo.com">Ronaldo</a>');
```

This code is working properly but the issue is, it's also replacing `Ronaldo` in title and in heading. I don't want that. I want that code to only replace words in `post-body` and not on `post-title` or `<h>` tags

I'm tagging jquery and ajax because they too know javascript.

Comment: Show the location of your text, pls

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting whole body with : `document.body;`
when you can just select the specific one by using: `document.getElementById("yourId");`
and replaces it's Ronaldo.